# Does Resharper detect changes in settings from settings file imported via 'This Computer'?

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2022

I have imported resharper settings in Visual Studio 2022 via 'Resharper - Settings Layers' -> 'This computer' -> 'Open settings file'. The settings file is located on a network shared file system and currently still being edited by other team members. Does resharper automatically detect changes made to the settings file and apply them accordingly, e.g. when executing a code-cleanup?

When a setting in the settings file was changed, it did not seem to be applied in Visual Studio when doing a code cleanup. Reloading the VS solution did not help.

Comment: Yes, R# is supposed to detect changes to a .dotsettings file and apply them on-the-fly. I'd first check if it is a problem with the network file system and can be reproduced with a local file.